# Answers voted on before answer is created in Data Explorer

Tags: bug, data-explorer, data-dump

When using the Data Explorer for Stack Overflow, I've found some cases of answers having votes before their creation date. For example, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/346612) shows the first vote being made `2011-07-09`, while the answer was created on `2011-07-10`.

My assumption is that this is because the `Votes` table does some sort of rounding on its columns (evidenced by the `00:00:00` timestamp), while the `Posts` table takes exact date times. Is there something else going on that I'm missing?

Comment: David, how did you find the post creation date '2011-07-10'? Can you link me to the question.

Comment: The answer with the problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639001/android-how-does-google-instant-upload-work/6639103#6639103

Comment: The [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6639001/timeline?asc=True) also shows that +1 on the answer preceded the answer being posted.

Comment: @David read the answers from the above and comments on the Marc Gravell post